# Why is the error thrown although the if-clause is false?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why is the error thrown in this code?

The objects properties have the following values (output by method `addGroup()`):

```
####### ADDGROUP ######                                                                                                                                                                            
isBasic: 0                                                                                                                                                                                         
types[0]: Z                                                                                                                                                                                        
####### ADDGROUP ######
```

So since `isBasic` is false and `types[0]` = Z (as shown in the output above) the error should not be thrown in my understanding:

```
void addGroup(int newGroup) {
    cout<<"####### ADDGROUP ######"<<endl;
    cout<<"isBasic: ";
    cout<<isBasic<<endl;

    cout<<"types[0]: ";
    cout<<types[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"####### ADDGROUP ######"<<endl;

  if(isBasic == true && types[0] != 'Z') {
    #error "Sensor defined as basicComponent, type(s) already set. Basic component is either group- OR type-specific but never both!"
  }

  for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
    if(groups[i] == 99) {
      groups[i] = newGroup;
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A `#error` is a compiler directive to halt compilation with an error.

Comment: _Throwing_ errors in C++ is made using [exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#error` is a preprocessor directive. It happens at compile-time and doesn't care about your runtime activity (such as your `if()` statement).

If you want a compile-time error, then you need to use compile-time directives like `#if`.

If you want a runtime error, then you need to use runtime error throwing like `throw` et al.

Comment: Ha :) Exact same first sentence

Comment: I chose this answer as "correct" answer due to the hint about `throw`.

Answer (score 3):

`#error` is a preprocessor directive. The error will always be processed unless it is removed by `#if` or similar preprocessor directive.

Preprocessing happens before compilation. Runtime conditions cannot affect it.